# Why does CTE inside a stored procedure take a very long time compared to CTE w/o stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I have a recursive CTE that calculates a manager hierarchy in an organization.

This below query takes < 2 seconds to finish

```
WITH OrganisationChart ([Identity], [DisplayName], Title, [Level], Manager) AS
(
      SELECT
            [Identity], [DisplayName], Title, 0, Manager
      FROM
            [data].[DailyUserV1] 
      WHERE 
            [Identity] = '7276DB4F-33B0-4074-9903-D95D740A8BF3' AND Date = '2015-08-03'

      UNION ALL 

      SELECT
            emp.[Identity], 
            emp.[DisplayName], 
            emp.Title, 
            [Level] + 1, 
            emp.Manager
      FROM
          [data].[DailyUserV1]  emp 
      INNER JOIN 
          OrganisationChart ON emp.Manager = OrganisationChart.[Identity]
      WHERE 
          Date = '2015-08-03'
)
SELECT * FROM OrganisationChart
```

While this same query wrapped inside a stored procedure takes > 15 mins and then times out!

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[GetOrganizationChart]') IS NOT NULL)
   DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetOrganizationChart]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetOrganizationChart]
     @identity varchar(256),
     @date datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @userId varchar(256);
    SET @userId = @identity;

    DECLARE @endDate datetime;
    SET @endDate = @date;

    WITH OrganisationChart ([Identity], [DisplayName], Title, [Level], Manager) AS
    (
         SELECT
             [Identity], [DisplayName], Title, 0, Manager
         FROM
             [data].[DailyUserV1] 
         WHERE 
             [Identity] = @userId AND Date = @endDate

         UNION ALL 

         SELECT
             emp.[Identity], 
             emp.[DisplayName], 
             emp.Title, 
             [Level] + 1, 
             emp.Manager
         FROM
             [data].[DailyUserV1]  emp 
         INNER JOIN 
             OrganisationChart ON emp.Manager = OrganisationChart.[Identity]
         WHERE 
             Date = @endDate
    )
SELECT * FROM OrganisationChart;
END
GO

EXEC [dbo].[GetOrganizationChart] @identity = '7276DB4F-33B0-4074-9903-D95D740A8BF3', @date = '2015-08-03'
```

I have ruled out parameter sniffing as a likely cause by using local variables inside the stored procedure. What's going on here?

**UPDATE**

Here are the links to the query execution plans in case you want to take a look.

[cte-without-stored-proc](http://pastebin.com/PbgaWNYm)
[cte-with-stored-proc](http://pastebin.com/1S7zfdQ9)

Comment: I'd also suspect the local variables `@userId` and `@endDate`  to be the problem...

Comment: Why do you suspect the local variables to be the problem? My first try was not to use any local variables but it still has the same problem

Comment: can you share the execution plan for ad-hoc and the stored procedure?

Comment: Smells like parameter sniffing to me. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/

Comment: @SeanLange The local variables will avoid any parameter sniffing problem.

Comment: updated the Q with links to execution plan XMLs

Comment: Same question over and over again. [Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#varparamreplace). `the query they are struggling with refer to variables, be that local variables or parameters. To troubleshoot the query on its own, they have replaced the variables with constants. But as we have seen, the resulting stand-alone query is quite different,`  and **`SQL Server can make more accurate estimates with constants instead of variables, and therefore arrive at a better plan`**

Answer (score 1):

The same problem I've faced earlier and there was parameter sniffing. To overcome this issue I used temporary table instead of CTE and the SP start running smoothly.